# What kind of shoes do you need in order to run on the sand?

Tags: running-shoes

Running on the sand of the beach is supposed to be harder for your leg muscles and perhaps less stressful on your joints. What kind of shoes are best for that? Normal jogging shoes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually none.  I tried several things including swimming "socks".  It doesn't matter, sand gets in them and drives you nuts.  Barefoot is the way to go.  You will get used to it after just a couple weeks.

Comment: ...provided that you don't inadvertently run with your bare foot on a small stone or shell and spend months on a pair of crutches due to a plantar fasciitis... Well, +1 and thanks anyway.

Comment: Well I have gotten cuts on my feet bottoms and they generally don't hurt and heal quick - and you learn where not to run.  Also I have had plantar fasciitis issues in my life - mainly when I ramp up long distance running or basketball... And now that I think of it, never an issue when I was running on sand a lot.  Very soft surface to run on and is a great leg work.

Comment: @DMoore I will agree wholeheartedly with this. Some of my best running experiences ever was on Dockweiler State Beach running barefoot. Using shoes was nothing but a hassle with tons of sand in the shoes.